# database connection with OPENSHIFT

Tags: php, mysql, database, openshift

i am try to connect phpmyadmin database using my php script in OPENSHIFT
[i am using sftp to upload file in openshift](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift)

doing this for connection

**index.php**

```
<?php 
 try {
                require_once 'conf.php';
                $conn = mysqlConnector();
                $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM demo');
                $stmt->execute();

                while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                        print_r($row);          
                }


        } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

?>
```

**conf.php**

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', getenv('127.*.**.*'));
define('DB_PORT',getenv('****')); 
define('DB_USER',getenv('admin4*****'));
define('DB_PASS',getenv('databasePassword'));
define('DB_NAME',getenv('ssh://5348030a***************@landbayscaling-innovifytest.rhcloud.com/~/git/landbayscaling.git/'));

function mysqlConnector(){
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.DB_BASE.';host='.DB_HOST.';port='.DB_PORT;
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
    }
?>
```

[Url Of Opensift](http://landbayscaling-innovifytest.rhcloud.com/)

Error is this:-

**ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)**

Comment: did you fin a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

DB_NAME is incorrect, you should use your app name, also, why are you using the values inside of getenv? You should be using the names of the environment variables, such as 
getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST')